# Show that the equation $x^3 +\sin x+\cos x = 0$; $\left[−\frac\pi4,0\right]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Show that the equation $x^3 +\sin x+\cos x = 0$ cannot have more than one solution in the interval $\left[-\frac\pi4,0\right]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we put $\;f(x)=x^3+\sin x+\cos x\;$ , then $\;f\left(-\frac\pi4\right)=-\frac{\pi^3}{64}-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}=-\frac{\pi^3}{64}<0\;$ , whereas $\;f(0)=1>0\;$. So by the IVT (why can we use this here?) there's a solution to $\;f(x)=0\;$ .

To show this solution is unique prove now that $\;f'(x)>0\;$ in the given interval (why is this enough?)

Comment: OP didn't ask for existence, though...

Comment: yes, thank you ı have one more question if you can answer

Comment: Show that the equation has at least one solution in the interval

Comment: @CanAkıncı That's already done there...

Comment: Why the downvote ? +1